# How to sort a column having numbers only in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Sorting does not work in the columns that have only integer values. It compares number by number. A solution for that will be appreciated. Defining the column numeric doesn't work. Does it need to change something else? I have added the few values to the table for clarity.

[Attachedimage is of descending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9nGH.png)

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tblLocks').dataTable();
});
```

```html
   

 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table display table-condensed table-striped table-hover locations-table" id="tblLocks">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="">Serial Number</th>
      <th class="name">Customer Name)</th>
      <th class="">Customer Code)</th>
      <th class="">Manufacture Date)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>68</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>29944</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>98</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>28631003</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631001</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631068</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>2865</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631034</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631056</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>286</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  
   <tr>
     <td>56</td>
     <td>H</td>
     <td>2811</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

JS:

```
var table = $('#tblLocks').DataTable({
 responsive: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            },



    ajax:{
    
url: "@Url.Action("LoadLocks", "Locks")",
                   
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    dataSrc: function (json) {
                            return json.data["LockCommonViewModels"];
                        }
                    },
    
 

columns: [
                    { data: "SerialNumber", name: "SerialNumber", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "CustomerName", name: "CustomerName", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "CustomerCode", name: "CustomerCode", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "ManufactureDate", name: "ManufactureDate", autoWidth: true },
            ],
    order: [[3, "desc"]]
            });
```

Comment: Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can have a better idea of what your data is. Please include HTML and JS so we can replicate this functionality.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819169/columns-with-numbers-does-not-sorts-properly-in-datatable) asked a few hours ago. It would be better to edit that other question instead of opening a new (identical) question.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors (eg `Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined` means your `targets` is wrong.   A quick check shows that you need `num` which works with either no target or with a target  https://jsfiddle.net/309f5pde/.  Not providing a columnDefs will sort on first column and auto-magically determine it's a num. Note that targets:0 is the left column (not targets:1) so `targets:2` is the 3rd column (this would be confirmable if you provided an example).  Otherwise there's nothing wrong with the code **as provided** - so we need more info to determine the issue.

Comment: Hi, your question(s) are getting closed because other users are indicating that you're not including enough information. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info which describes how to setup a snippet with datatables (click the `[<>]` button when editing your question)

Comment: @freedomn-m check my code

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Check my js and html

Comment: You're getting there - as you've taken the first step, I've converted your HTML to a datatables snippet for you.   I see you're using ajax to load the data - that doesn't help when debugging, so the next step is for you to update the snippet to include some *sample* data to show it not working - as you can see, using your code as provided originally shows that it works fine.  As mentioned on your other question by @andrewjames - it could simply be the data you're loading

Comment: @freedomn-m check now

Comment: @AnkiniDesai - Thank you for updating the question. However, your demo does not reproduce the problem. It works just fine. Did you run it for yourself? (click on the "run code snippet" blue button). So, we still cannot help you. We need the "R" in "MRE" (reproducible).

Comment: @andrewjames I did. also I added more records so that we can compare the results.

Comment: Here is my _complete guess_ again, transferred from the other question: Look at every value in that column. If even one value is not numeric (or cannot be treated as numeric by DataTables), then the entire column will be treated as string data, and will be sorted as strings, not as numbers. May be worth a careful check?

Comment: @andrewjames I have no idea how come it works here and not on my local. The datatype of the customer code getting from the server side is a string.

Comment: _I have no idea how come it works here and not on my local_ And neither do we, unfortunately. Until you can reproduce the problem, we cannot help you. And I suspect as soon as you can reproduce the problem, you will know how to solve the problem. Check the data. Check it very carefully. Somewhere in that data I suspect there is something non-numeric hiding. Anyway, for what it's worth, I voted to re-open the question. Good luck! I hope you can solve it. If you do, let us know.

Comment: Worth a try:  in the code you provided before I made it a working snippet, you had this: `<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>` - it *could* be that datatables is using this empty row to determine your columns before you load the data via ajax.  Try removing the `<tbody>` (and rows within) from the source and only loading via ajax.

Comment: `order: [[3, "desc"]]` is sorting on the fourth column, not the third (see the Comment tab at https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html). Are you sure you don't mean `order: [[2, "desc"]]` to sort on the third column (presumably `CustomerCode`)? Additionally, it looks like you can explicitly tell it the `type` of data in a column (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) which may be worth a shot.

Comment: Sure @andrewjames I will look into it. Really appreciate your help in voting this question to re-open.

Comment: @freedomn-m Removing <tbody><tr></tr></tbody>  doesnt helps :(

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: On page load, it should sort on manufacture date so that's how I set the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this is sorting as if the column `type` is a string. But there is a setting (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) to override the default interpretation where you can tell it what type of data is in each column (null for default interpretation).

You can see the different sorting variations on columns 3 and 4 in the example below depending on if it reads the data as a string or a num. If you sort on the `CustomerCode (num)` column this works as you are suggesting it should, but if you sort on the `CustomerCode (string)` column it's sorting as your example shows.

I suggest explicitly setting this value for the `CustomerCode` column, and sorting should work as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblLocks').dataTable({
    order: [
      [2, "desc"]
    ],
    "columns": [
      null,
      null,
      {
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "type": "num"
      },
      null
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table display table-condensed table-striped table-hover locations-table" id="tblLocks">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="">Serial Number</th>
      <th class="name">Customer Name</th>
      <th class="">Customer Code (string)</th>
      <th class="">Customer Code (num)</th>
      <th class="">Manufacture Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>68</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>29944</td>
      <td>29944</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>98</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>28631003</td>
      <td>28631003</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631001</td>
      <td>28631001</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631068</td>
      <td>28631068</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>2865</td>
      <td>2865</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631034</td>
      <td>28631034</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>28631056</td>
      <td>28631056</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>286</td>
      <td>286</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>2811</td>
      <td>2811</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: So here in the code, the values are hardcoded. But in mine, ajax brings the JSON results and when I try the code that you included defining the column as num, it keeps on loading. No data pops up in the table.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue/question then. This question is about sorting column data, and this is an apparent working solution to that. As mentioned in the comments, if you are able to provide a reproducible example of that functionality (in a new question) then the SO community can help you debug that separately. But without a reproducible example we won't really have much to go on.

Comment: It is very difficult to present a reproducible example using ajax in SO. However, I will try my best and really thanks for two separate examples.

Comment: I realize the difficulty in demonstrating an ajax issue in an SO question, but half of the purpose of enforcing good question writing on this site is demonstrating good debugging skills in the first place. I've often run into this, where as soon as I write the question, I'm able to solve the issue because the question-writing process forces me to think and explain in a very specific way - details that you might normally gloss over when debugging on your own, you now have to explain the specifics of. And that can reveal assumptions in your code that you thought might've been unrelated. :)

Comment: @AnkiniDesai - _It is very difficult to present a reproducible example using ajax in SO_ Yes, it can be. Which is why the suggested approach in such circumstances is to _supplement_ your detailed SO question with a link to a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [JS Bin](http://live.datatables.net/) or similar. That was something that freedomn-m did already suggest in an earlier comment. If you have never used either of those tools, they are worth learning - and are easy to use.